# Magento 1.9 after clearing layout cache now have white screen

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error

Ever since i cleared the layout cache in magento my website now has a blank white screen i've tried to find the error by adding the following in my index.php file but returns nothing.

> ```
>   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
>   register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
>    function fatal_handler() {
>      $error = error_get_last();
>      echo("<pre>");
>      print_r($error);
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try clearing the entire contents of var/cache folder if you haven't already. Then disable any custom modules in app/etc/modules. Keep clearing var/cache folder each time you try anything.

If you cleared the layout cache the problem may be that the cache cannot rebuild itself because of folder/file permissions.

The suggestions here may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen